# Vertical space problem with theorem environment and (sub)section title

Tags: formatting, titles, theorems, vertical-spacing, newtheorem

I've define a new theorem environment :

```
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{
    \def\FrameCommand
    {
        {\color{ffg_title_color}\vrule width 3pt}
        \hspace{0pt}
    }
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}
}
{\endMakeFramed}

\newtheoremstyle{new_theorem_style}
    {\topsep}           % space before \topsep
    {\topsep}           % space after\topsep
    {\itshape}          % body font
    {}                  % indent
    {\bfseries}         % header font
    {}                  % punctuation
    {\newline}          % after theorem header
    {\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{\ -\ #3}\\*[-1.5ex]}% header specification (empty for default)

\theoremstyle{new_theorem_style}
\newtheorem*{definitionT}{\color{ffg_title_color}{Définition}}
\newenvironment{definition}
{
    \begin{leftbar}
        \begin{definitionT}
            \mbox{}\noindent\ignorespaces}{
        \end{definitionT}
    \end{leftbar}
}
```

I've define specific title format too

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
    {\fontsize{13pt}{12pt}\selectfont\color{ffg_title_color}}
    {\quad \thesubsection \quad #1}
    {0pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
    {0pt}
    {18pt}
    {0pt}

\titleformat{name=\subsection, numberless}[display]
    {\fontsize{13pt}{12pt}\selectfont\color{ffg_title_color}}
    {\quad #1}
    {0pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
    {0pt}
    {18pt}
    {0pt}

% SUBSUBSECTION title
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]
    {\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont\color{ffg_title_color}}
    {\qquad \thesubsubsection \quad #1}
    {0pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
    {0pt}
    {12pt}
    {-10pt}
```

And the result is a little bit strange when I put these two pieces together : the space between a title and the definition it too big and, at the opposite, the space between the definition and the next title is too short.

[image]

Can you help me to correct this situation ? Thank you in advance !

Here is my mwe :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report} % report, article, book

\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}  % Gestion des marges
\usepackage[french]{babel}                                  % Gestion du français
\usepackage{xcolor}                                         % Gestion des couleurs
\usepackage{textcomp}                                       % Caractères additionnels
\usepackage{mathtools, amsmath, amstext, amssymb, amsthm}   % Package de l'AMS + mathtools
\usepackage{xspace}                                         % Gestion intelligente de l'espace après une commande
\usepackage{lmodern}                                        % Police de caractère
\usepackage{calc}                                           % Syntaxe naturelle pour les calculs
\usepackage{framed}

% Layout fisrt page
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}                      % Gestion des positions du texte (option de config : showboxes)
\usepackage{fontspec}                               % Gestion de "arial" ET "arial narrow" comme font.

% Layout Document 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}                     % Gestion des sections
\usepackage{titletoc}                               % Gestion de la table des matière
\usepackage{titling}                                % Gestion des titres

% Tools kit
\usepackage{etoolbox}                               % Renew command & robust command

% other package
\usepackage{bm}                                     % Notation mathématique en gras

\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% (Re)Define parametres for document
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\setmainfont{Arial}

% Color definition
\definecolor{ffg_darkblue}{RGB}{21,29,76}
\definecolor{ffg_lightblue}{RGB}{0, 120, 190}
\definecolor{ffg_red}{RGB}{241, 83, 60}

\definecolor{ffg_title_color}{RGB}{12, 97, 158}
\definecolor{ffg_section_color}{RGB}{24, 146, 239}

\definecolor{footer_color}{RGB}{128, 128, 128}

\setlength\fboxrule{0.75pt}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\fbox{$~~~ \displaystyle#1 ~~~$}}

% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Titles layout redefinition
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\makeatletter

% SECTION title
\titleformat{\section}[display]
    {\fontsize{14pt}{12pt}\selectfont\color{ffg_section_color}}
    {\thesection \qquad #1}
    {0pt}
    {}
    [\vspace{-4mm} {\color{ffg_lightblue}\titlerule[.6mm]} \enlargethispage{-\parskip}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
    {0pt}   % left
    {24pt}   % top
    {10pt}   % bottom

\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[display]
    {\fontsize{14pt}{12pt}\selectfont\color{ffg_section_color}}
    {\thesection \qquad #1}
    {0pt}
    {}
    [\vspace{-4mm} {\color{ffg_lightblue}\titlerule[.6mm]} \enlargethispage{-\parskip}]

% SUBSECTION title
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
    {\fontsize{13pt}{12pt}\selectfont\color{ffg_title_color}}
    {\quad \thesubsection \quad #1}
    {0pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
    {0pt}
    {18pt}
    {0pt}

\titleformat{name=\subsection, numberless}[display]
    {\fontsize{13pt}{12pt}\selectfont\color{ffg_title_color}}
    {\quad #1}
    {0pt}
    {}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
    {0pt}
    {18pt}
    {0pt}

\makeatother


% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
% Redefine Theoreme & Definition
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %
\renewenvironment{leftbar}[1][\hsize]
{
    \def\FrameCommand
    {
        {\color{ffg_title_color}\vrule width 3pt}
        \hspace{0pt}
    }
    \MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}
}
{\endMakeFramed}

\newtheoremstyle{new_theorem_style}
    {\topsep}           % space before \topsep
    {\topsep}           % space after\topsep
    {\itshape}          % body font
    {}                  % indent
    {\bfseries}         % header font
    {}                  % punctuation
    {\newline}          % after theorem header
    {\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{\ -\ #3}\\*[-1.5ex]}% header specification (empty for default)

\theoremstyle{new_theorem_style}
\newtheorem*{definitionT}{\color{ffg_title_color}{Définition}}
\newenvironment{definition}
{
    \begin{leftbar}
        \begin{definitionT}
            \mbox{}\noindent\ignorespaces}{
        \end{definitionT}
    \end{leftbar}
}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                               CHAPTER                                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \chapter{Rappels}
\section{Corps}
\subsection{Masse d'un corps}
\begin{definition}
    La masse (notée $m$ et exprimée en kg) d'un corps mesure la quantité de matière constituant ce corps, c'est à dire la masse des particules qui constituent ce corps.
\end{definition}
Cette quantité de matière est invariable quel que soit l'endroit où se trouve l'objet dans l'Univers, et quelles que soient les forces qui s'exercent sur lui.

\subsection{Poids d'un corps}
\begin{definition}
    Force d'attraction qu'exerce un astre sur un corps massique.
\end{definition}

Sur terre, le poids se calcule par la formule suivante :

\[\mybox{P = m \times g}\]

Où :
\begin{itemize}
    \item $P$ : poids du corps (en $N$)
    \item $m$ : masse du corps (en $kg$)
    \item $g$ : constante de pesanteur (à la surface de la Terre : $9,81\ m/s^2$)\par
\end{itemize}

La pesanteur terrestre est une accélération verticale, dirigée vers le bas, qui s'applique sur tous les corps possédant une masse et situés au voisinage de la Terre.

\subsection{Corps isolé}
\begin{definition}
    Un corps isolé est un corps sur lequel ne s'exerce aucune force.
\end{definition}

\subsection{Corps pseudo-isolé}
\begin{definition}
    Un corps isolé est un corps sur lequel la résultante des forces s'exerçant sur lui est nulle
\end{definition}

\section{Centre de gravité}
\begin{definition}
    Le centre de gravité ($CG$) est le point théorique d'application de la résultante des actions de la pesanteur sur toutes les parties du corps.
\end{definition}

Le corps humain est de densité non uniforme et de forme irrégulière : pour une personne en station debout, le centre de gravité se situe approximativement en avant de la troisième vertèbre lombaire (en direction du nombril).
Ce point n'est jamais fixe, il varie en fonction de la position du corps.
C'est un point virtuel qui n'a donc pas d'existence physique réelle.\medskip

% Rajouter quelques images de centre de gravité !

En gymnastique, comme dans la vie courante, le corps humain peut adopter différentes postures (debout, assis, groupé, carpé, tendu, \ldots).
Le $CG$ se déplace suivant la position des différentes parties du corps car les masses se répartissent différemment.
Il peut même arriver qu'il se situe en dehors du corps.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question title and tags suggest you are not satisfied with the horizontal spacing around your theorems, while the body of the question itself is more about the vertical white space between theorems and preceding or following section titles. Could you please clarify that?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. It's corrected now.